# Non-vanishing of archimedean integral representations

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, analytic-number-theory, l-functions

Let $\psi$ denote a non-trivial additive character of $\mathbb{R}$ and $n$ be a positive integer. Let $(\pi,V)$ and $(\pi',V')$ be two irreducible generic Casselman-Wallach representations of $G_n=\operatorname{GL}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ on Frechet spaces $V$ and $V'$ respectively.

Further, let $\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi)$ and $\mathcal{W}(\pi',\psi^{-1})$ denote the Whittaker models of $\pi$ and $\pi'$ respectively. Finally, set $\mathcal{S}_n$ to be the space of Schwartz functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Consider the following family of integrals:
$$\mathcal{J}=\{I(s,W,W',\Phi):W\in\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi),W'\in\mathcal{W}(\pi',\psi^{-1}),\Phi\in\mathcal{S}_n\}$$
defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
&I(s, W,W', \Phi) \\
&=\int_{N_n \backslash G L_n} W\left(g\right)W'\left(g\right)\Phi(e_ng)|\operatorname{det}(g)|^{s} d g,
\end{aligned}
$$

$e_n=(0,0,...,0,1)\in\mathbb{R}^n.$

$N_n$  is the group of upper triangular matrices with unit diagonal over $\mathbb{R}.$

I have the following set of questions:

$(1)$ Is is true that for every $s_0\in\mathbb{C}$, there exist $W\in\mathcal{W}(\pi,\psi),W'\in\mathcal{W}(\pi',\psi^{-1})$ and $\Phi\in\mathcal{S}_n$ such that $I(s, W,W', \Phi)\neq 0$.

$(2)$ Can the choice of $\Phi$ in $(1)$ be made such that $\Phi(0)=0$?

$(3)$ Are the questions $(1)$ and $(2)$ known for Asai and exterior square integral representations?

I am seeking information on these questions and would appreciate any guidance or references to relevant literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to (1) is yes. See Corollary 8.3.2 of ["Lectures on $L$-Functions, Converse Theorems, and Functoriality for $\mathrm{GL}_n$"](https://math.osu.edu/%7Ecogdell.1/fields-www.pdf) by Cogdell. (This is stated for $\mathrm{GL}_n \times \mathrm{GL}_m$ Rankin-Selberg integrals with $n > m$, but one can see from the sketch of how this follows from other results that this is also valid for $n = m$.) Some good related references are "Rankin-Selberg Convolutions: Archimedean Theory" by Jacquet and Shalika, ["Archimedean Rankin-Selberg Integrals"](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Ehj/PerfectRankinSelberg.pdf) by Jacquet, and ["Some Results on Archimedean Rankin-Selberg Integrals"](https://doi.org/10.2140/pjm.2015.273.277) by Chai.

(3) in the case of the Flicker integral (i.e. the Asai $L$-function) has been answered in Theorem 1 (iii) of ["Archimedean Theory and $\epsilon$-Factors for the Asai Rankin-Selberg Integrals"](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-68506-5_1) by Beuzart-Plessis. However, they do not specify whether $\Phi(0) = 0$, so (2) remains untreated.

Finally, recent work of mine and Jo shows something closely related, namely that there exist explicit choices of $W,W',\Phi$ for which the period integral of interest is equal to the $L$-function of interest times a polynomial in $s$. This polynomial in $s$ is explicit and is determined by $\pi$ and $\pi'$. Moreover, this result is also true for the Flicker integral and the Bump-Friedberg integral. See Theorems 5.6, 6.10, and 7.12 of ["Test Vectors for Archimedean Period Integrals"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2112.06860) by Humphries and Jo. I believe (but haven't double-checked) that our work actually answers your question (1) in the affirmative: we show that the integral is the $L$-function times a polynomial, and I believe that the $L$-function has a pole wherever the polynomial has a zero, so that you get nonvanishing. Moreover, the Schwartz function $\Phi$ is explicit in each case and satisfies $\Phi(0) = 0$ except in the special case that $\pi$ and $\pi'$ are both unramified.

Comment: Thanks for a detailed answer. Just wanted to add that I found the non-vanishing of archimedean exterior square integral representation in the following paper of Dustin Belt : https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1108.2200